# If value matches add it to list if not skip exel with python

Tags: python, pandas, function

I need to make my code check if the name of the carrier matches `1`. If so, add the value from column `Ref/Lic Nr` to a list, if not, skip. Right now I still get all values from `Ref/Lic Nr`, even if the carrier name is not `1`.

```python
import pandas as pd
b = [] <br />
data = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\1.xlsx')
cr = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Carrier'])
rf = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Ref/Lic Nr'])
if((cr['Carrier']==str('1')).any()):
    b.append(rf['Ref/Lic Nr'])
print(b)
```

Comment: Gave you tried str.startswith('1')?

Comment: wont it just return true of false?

Comment: When someone answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data.loc[data.Carrier==1, 'Ref/Lic Nr']` should give you refs for carrier 1

Comment: Thanks mate that worked
I spend to much time on this)) your the best)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import pandas as pd
b = []
data = pd.read_excel('files/1.xlsx')


for a in data.loc[data.Carrier == 1, 'Ref/Lic Nr']:
    b.append(a)
print(b)
```